# Racket Intersect Two Lists

Tags: list, scheme, racket

I am trying to intersect two lists on Racket, but the following code is not working:

```
(define (intersection a b)
  (if (null? a)
    '()
    (if (contains (car a) b)
      (cond (car a)(intersection (cdr a) b))
      (intersection (cdr a) b))))
```

The result always end up being the first item of list a that is contained in list b, plus the rest of list a. For example:

```
a = '(1 2 3 4 5 6)
b = '( 10 20 4 30 33)
```

Would return:

```
'(4 5 6)
```

I am sure that contains is working correctly, so the error must be in the code I posted. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cond` is a special form and an in place replacement for nested `if`. It seems to me that you didn't intend to check if `car` was true so that `a` would always be the result so I guess that what you actually wanted to use was `cons` instead:

```
(define (intersection a b)
  (if (null? a)
      '()
      (if (contains (car a) b)
          (cons (car a) (intersection (cdr a) b))
          (intersection (cdr a) b))))

(define contains member) ; contains wasn't defined by I guess member will do

(intersection '(1 2 3 4 7) '(3 4 5 6)) ; ==> (3 4)
```

Answer (score 5):

Hey if you're not doing that for fun you can use Racket's [set-intersect](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/sets.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fset..rkt%29._set-intersect%29%29) function

```
(set-intersect '(1 2 3 4 7) '(3 4 5 6)) ; => '(4 3)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. It was for an assignment. Since the error was not conceptual I was allowed to go online for help =P