# is there any way to find the intersection of two lists of strings using recursion? Dr. Racket

Tags: list, recursion, racket

```
(define (both d1 d2) (cond
                   [(or (empty? d2) (empty? d1)) empty]
                   [(string=? (first d1) (first d2)) (cons (first d1) (both (rest d1) (rest d2)))]
                   [else (both d1 (rest d2))]))
```

I have written this code in racket but I can't find a way to recurse the first list. Im pretty new to dr. racket so I'd prefer in the solution only had basic built-in functions.
I saw the other post about the same question but I'm trying to do this using only recursion.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Racket Intersect Two Lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550377/racket-intersect-two-lists)

Comment: The accepted answer in the question above is pretty elementary and uses recursion. If you really want to explicitly recurse both lists, all you need to do is write your own `contains` function. (also Dr. Racket is an IDE, the language you are using is whatever is defined as `#lang` at the top of your Racket file

Comment: What do you consider a "basic built-in function"? Most would regard `member` as both basic and built-in, since it's part of the racket/base package.